# Activar y desactivar la consola (redirección de cout y cerr en Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, consola

Tengo un código que me cierra o abre la consola y debería redireccionar allí `cout` y `cerr` :

```
static std::ofstream console_stream;
// Guardamos los búferes originales de 'cout' y 'cerr'.
static std::streambuf *const out{ std::cout.rdbuf() }, *const err{ std::cout.rdbuf() };

// Cierra el stream si estaba abierto.
void close_stream(std::ofstream &o)
{
    if (o.is_open())
        o.close();
}

// Restablece los búferes de 'cout' y 'cerr'.
void restore()
{
    std::cout.rdbuf(out);
    std::cerr.rdbuf(err);
}

// Abre un stream al archivo indicado y redirecciona dicho stream a 'cout' y 'cerr'.
void open_and_redirect_to(const std::string &file, std::ofstream &o)
{
    if (o.open(file); o)
    {
        std::cout.rdbuf(o.rdbuf());
        std::cerr.rdbuf(o.rdbuf());
    }
}

// Cierra o abre la consola
void console(bool open)
{
    if (open)
    {
        if (!GetConsoleWindow())
        {
            if (AllocConsole())
            {
                close_stream(console_stream);
                restore();

                open_and_redirect_to("CONOUT$", console_stream);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (GetConsoleWindow())
        {
            close_stream(console_stream);
            restore();

            FreeConsole();
        }
    }
}
```

Cuando lo pruebo:

```
int main()
{
    console(false);
    console(true);

    using namespace std::chrono_literals;

    for (unsigned i{}; i != 100; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << std::format("{}\tApplication running...\n", i);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1234ms);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

En mi equipo aparecen dos ventanas de consola, la primera es la que se cerró en la llamada `console(false);` y la segunda es la que se abrió en la llamada `console(true);`. En ninguna de ellas hay texto alguno, en la primera ventana es normal que no lo haya pues se cerró antes de ninguna llamada a `std::cout` pero esperaba que se mostrara texto en la segunda.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 2):

No hay nada malo con tu código. Aparentemente la información se envía correctamente aunque por algún motivo que desconozco los cambios no se reflejan automáticamente. Es necesario que llames la función `flush` cada vez manualmente.

Lo que sí me dio resultados fue llamar a `freopen` o su versión segura como indica [este comentario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543571/allocconsole-not-displaying-cout#comment79236398_15547699):

```
freopen_s((FILE**)stdin, "CONIN$", "r", stdin);
freopen_s((FILE**)stdout, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
freopen_s((FILE**)stderr, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
```

Estas son las modificaciones que tendrías que hacer para no necesitar llamar a `flush` a cada rato.

```
if (AllocConsole())
{
     close_stream(console_stream);

     freopen_s((FILE**)stdin, "CONIN$", "r", stdin);
     freopen_s((FILE**)stdout, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
     freopen_s((FILE**)stderr, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
}
```

Comment: Ya lo había probado con `freopen`, pero esa función pertenece a las cabeceras importadas desde [tag:c] y quería una solución de [tag:c++] puro; me parece muy raro que no sea posible.